# Question to an exact ODE, integrating factor does not work out

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We got

$$x'=\frac{t^2x^2+1}{2t^2}$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{t^2x^2+1}{2t^2}$$

$$2t^2dx=\left(t^2x^2+1\right)dt$$

$$0=\left(t^2x^2+1\right)dt+\left(-2t^2dx\right)$$

I get the integrating factor

$$\mu \left(t\right)=\frac{e^{x+2}}{t}$$

But it doesn't really work out!

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

$$x'=\frac{t^2x^2+1}{2t^2}$$
$$x'=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2t^2}$$
Change the variable
$$x=u-\dfrac 1t$$
$$u'=\frac{u^2}{2}-\dfrac ut$$
This is Bernoulli 's differential equation. You can put it in the following form for $u \ne 0$:
$$\dfrac {d(ut)}{(ut)^2}=\dfrac {dt}{2t}$$
Integrate.
$$\dfrac {2}{(ut)}=k-\ln  t$$
$$u=\dfrac 2{t(k-\ln t)}$$
$$x(t)=\dfrac 2{t(k-\ln t)}-\dfrac 1t$$

For $u=0$ you have that: $$x(t)=-\dfrac 1 t$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the substitution $tx = v$:

$$\frac{v'}{t}-\frac{v}{t^2} = \frac{v^2+1}{2t^2} \implies 2tv' = (v+1)^2$$

from here it is separable with solution

$$x = \frac{2}{Ct-t\log t} - \frac{1}{t}$$

Comment: How do you get to this solution to x? I get something different, namely $x=\frac{-2-t-C}{t^2+Ct}$

Comment: Sorry, it's something entirely different than I've written, but it's still does not match your solution, it's something with ln etc, just put it in symbolab and youll see

Comment: @Dan I fixed it.